# How to join intermediate table in ManyToMany mappings in the hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, many-to-many

Is there a way I can join intermediate table in the `ManyToMany` table. You can consider the example given at https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

[image]

As an example in the above `Student` to `Course` many to many relation, we can have tables `STUDENT`, `COURSE` and `STUDENT_COURSE`.

My question is to check if there is any way we can provide this in hibernate in java so that `Student` class has mapping for `STUDENT_COURSE` intermediate table instead of `COURSE` table?

I want to modify below class to get the above output:-

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>(0);

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public Student(String studentName, Set<Course> courses) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    public long getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE",
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID") })
    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return this.courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what you want to achieve? ManyToMany relations always lead to intermediate tables, so you will have STUDENT, COURSE and STUDENT_COURSE tables. Hibernate hides intermediate table (in hql queries) and you deal with entities, not tables

Comment: So my concern is since the existing implementation will have join queries for 2 tables, but i want to cache some information for 1 table in order to optimize the performance and let the hibernate query till the intermediate table

Comment: Essentially Course Id and Course Name would be maintained locally and i just want to fetch the course Ids from STUDENT_COURSE table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

you should divide your many to many association to two many to one association and use @Embedded annotation to define compound key for your intermediate entity
look at below link for detail

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Long answer:

Actually when you use @ManyToMany annotation to establish many to many association in hibernate it creates another table to establish ManyToMany association behind the scene  this table is defined with @JoinTable annotation in your code, query to that table is completely managed by hibernate to achieve many to many association and you don't have  entity which  is mapped to that table. It is fine unless you need extra column in your intermediate table(here STUDENT_COURSE) or you want to execute some specific query to that table in a way that you behave with your other entity and you want to access the Id of your Course and Student table in CourseStudent table. because when hibernate creates intermediate table behind the scene you don't have entity in your program  that maps to that table and therefore you can't have other column for that table and you can't behave to that table as an entity in your program. if you need extra column you can divide your @ManyToMany association to two @ManyToOne association. Here you should have another entity with name StudentCourse which has two @ManyToOne association one to Student entity and the other one to Course entity. However when you are defining your many to many association this way you should consider data integriry for instance the combination of student_id and course_id in your student_course table is unique and actually it should be a compound key in your student_course table. Fortunately there are some annotations in hibernate and jpa that provide this capability. Writing all the code for this sitiuation in this answer is redundant because there is already a good example in the link below .

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is late but hopefully, it'll help somebody.

I guess you wanna do some queries on the intermediate table. In that case, you can use native query, something like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT student_id FROM student_course WHERE course_id =:courseId",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Integer>findAllStudentIdFromCourseId(Integer courseId);
```